# Customizing Telescope app with Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, telescope

My simple question is: how do I link a logo to the title of my app.

Which begs the greater question: How exactly do I interact with the telescope template in the best way through heroku. Linking with dropbox has left me with a folder with only 2 code files that simply link to the a page on how to launch your telescope app wit heroku and git.

In short, How exactly do best I interact with my telescope app. I have an understanding on html/css and some javascript/php/python

I only want to make simple aesthetic changes, but I really just want to know how to communicate.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing… I'm not really sure if you're asking how to customize a Telescope app, update a Heroku instane, or both…? In any case you should find the answer to all this in the Telescope documentation: http://docs.telescopeapp.org/

Answer (score 0):

In order to make aesthetic changes you need to change the templates and add CSS files as needed.  To interact with the templates look into adding HTML [classes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) and [IDs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) to your elements and then make the aesthetic changes in a CSS file to the elements with the [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

You should not need to change anything in Heroku because it should already be set up to serve the files that already exist.

After you make the changes perhaps you should look into [deploying with meteor itself](https://www.meteor.com/try/6) rather than using Heroku.

Comment: thank you! my probelm is that i have no idea where the css and html files that telescope has provided me can be accssed and edited. and moving forward if i find them, I would want to know how to make sure i could inject some surface changes without meddling with the core code.

Comment: Editing the CSS will definitely not change the core code and editing HTML to just add classes and IDs won't either. If you can't find any CSS files at all then perhaps there are none. At the very least you can create your own and define something obvious (like change the background color of the page) to see if it works. If it does make your surface changes in that file you just created.

Comment: I want to change the logo image but cant figure out what selector has already been assigned to it, where to look or if that's even the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to change the logo on the top banner you should actually be able to do that fairly easily through the Settings panel without needing any code. Log in on an admin account, then at top right go to Settings, then Logo.